# Is there a better way to replace rows from one dataframe to another based on a single columns' data?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm attempting to replace all matching rows in one dataframe with rows from another dataframe when a specific condition is satisfied. The number of rows in both dataframes will differ, but the number of columns are the same.

Do to the sensitive nature of the data that im dealing with i can give an example but not the real data itself.
An example of the dataframe could be something like this:

```
Location Tickets Destination Product Tare Net Scale Value1 Value2 ...
  500      012       ID        01A     20  40   60   0.01   0.00
  500      013       PA        02L     10  300  310  12.01    5
```

The other dataframe would have different values in each respective column, except for the 'Tickets' column. I would like to replace the data from all rows in df1 with any data from df2 that has a matching ticket number.

```
df1.loc[df1.Tickets.isin(df2.Tickets), :] = 
df2.loc[df2.Tickets.isin(df1.Tickets), :].values
```

When i had run the code i get this error off and on:

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray

Not sure why or what is causing it because the code works on certain dataframes and not on others. The dataframes it is working on have different numbers of rows but the same columns, which is exactly the same for the dataframes it's not working on. I know their is something to this but i can't seem to find it.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Update:

interestingly enough when i isolate the tickets to be replaced from df1 in a separate dataframe, i get no errors when i replace them with df2. This leads me to believe i have duplicate tickets in df1 that are causing my error but on further inspection i can find no duplicate tickets in df1.

Comment: Are all the values for `'Ticket'` unique within a dataframe? Also, I think this will only work if the order is the same in both dataframes, from a quick glance.

Comment: Yes all ticket values are unique in say the df1 dataframe, and all ticket numbers in df2 are unique from one another. They will however be the same from df1 to df2 in select rows

Comment: I will sort_values in order to get the second dataframe in order as it is not in ascending or descending order and get back to you shortly

Comment: Your error might occur when there is no match between datasets.

Comment: when i ordered the second dataset i have a new error that is: ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (111,62) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (115,62)

Comment: Shouldn't the .values take care of datasets not being the same size in terms of rows?

Comment: I only mentioned order because if the tickets are in different order, moving the data will change the order the tickets are in. Although this isn't a huge issue since you are moving the ticket id with it. But I'm not sure why you would get this new error from a sort. Did you see if the original error occurs when there is no ticket match between the dataframes?

Comment: All ticket numbers existing in df2 also exist in df1.

Comment: Hmm out of ideas here. Unfortunately it's hard to say what's going on without the actual data. You could always try to update pandas to see if it was a bug that was patched.